# How to find all methods available to SumConvergence?

Tags: options, summation, undocumented

Looking into [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132982/29926) made me suspect that `SumConvergence` might have more `Method`s available than the four listed in its documentation. How do I find all `Method`s available for this function?

*Edit:* For completeness let me add that, besides `Automatic`, the documentation mentions (note the vague choice of words: "possible values ... include")

> Possible values for Method include:
>   "IntegralTest" the integral test
>   "RaabeTest" Raabe's test
>   "RatioTest" D'Alembert ratio test
>   "RootTest" Cauchy root test

*Note:* The obvious adaption to the answer to [this similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35493/29926) does not seem to work; the same seems to be true for the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/29926).

Comment: The code within ``Sum`SumConvergenceDump`SumConvergenceTestMethod[]`` seems to show the names of the supported methods.

Comment: @J.M: Probably I'm very naive, but if I evaluate that noting happens; I just get back the input.

Comment: You need to have run `SumConvergence[]` first before trying ``??Sum`SumConvergenceDump`SumConvergenceTestMethod``.

Comment: I also see `"DivergenceTest"` in the code.

Comment: Thanks. Can we then be sure there are no further methods available? If so, please turn your comments into an answer that I will gladly accept.

Comment: Can't really say; that's what I got after cursory spelunking. Someone else who knows more than me might want to chime in instead.

Answer (score 3):

Like J.M., I see the `"DivergenceTest"` (Nth term test for divergence)
as well as user-defined methods.

The **`"DivergenceTest"`** can only be used to show divergence (return value `False`).  If it returns `True`, it is unreliable.

```
SumConvergence[1/n, n, Method -> "DivergenceTest"]
(*  True  *)
```

**User-defined methods** have the form `Method -> myConvTest`, where `myConvTest` has the form as `SumConvergence` (without options):

```
myConvTest[summand, variable]
```

Examples:

```
SumConvergence[1/n, n, Method -> (True &)] (* the optimistic test *)
(*  True  *)

myLCT[e_, k_] := SumConvergence[Normal[Series[e, {k, ∞, 2}]], k]
SumConvergence[Sin[50/n^2], n, Method -> myLCT]
(*  True  *)
```

[Discovered exploring [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163329/4999).]

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful addition to J.M.'s comments!