# SumConvergence difficulty

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 9, persisting through 11.2.**

---

Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{50}{n^2}$. The terms are eventually positive.

```
ListPlot[Table[Sin[50/n^2], {n, 1, 40}]]
```

Which produces this image.

[image]

Therefore, I was able to use the Limit Comparison Test.

```
a[n] := Sin[50/n^2]
b[n] := 50/n^2
Limit[a[n]/b[n], n -> ∞]
```

Which produced an answer of 1. Because this limit is strictly positive and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{50}{n^2}$ is convergent ($p$-series with $p=2>1$), by the Limit Comparison Test, the series  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{50}{n^2}$ is also convergent. However,

```
SumConvergence[Sin[50/n^2], n]
```

does not produce a "True" response. I also tried:

```
Assuming[n >= 10, SumConvergence[Sin[50/n^2], n]]
```

Which was also unsuccessful. Is this something I should report?

Comment: This must be a bug. In Version 8.0   'SumConvergence[Sin[50/n^2], n] ' yields the expected  'True'.

Comment: The issue is introduced in _v9_, since it just returns unevaluated rather than a wrong answer, I think it's better to call it a "backslide". @akku14

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `Sin` in the term triggers a heuristic check that prevents the integral test from being performed.  The assumption is that if the function contains `Sin`, then it is not monotonic, I suppose.

I don't know a good way around it, especially since I know you're usually interested in natural-looking methods that your students can understand without a bunch of complicated explanations.  Here's a proof of concept workaround, I suppose:

```
term /: Integrate[term[n_], args___] := (foo = Stack[]; Integrate[Sin[50/n^2], args]);
term[n_Integer] := Sin[50/n^2];
SumConvergence[term[n], n, Method -> "IntegralTest"]

(*  True  *)

foo
(*
  {SumConvergence, Block, CompoundExpression, CompoundExpression, Set, 
  Sum`SumConvergenceDump`iSumConvergence, Block, CompoundExpression, 
  Set, Quiet, Sum`SumConvergenceDump`SumConvergenceTestMethod, Block, 
  CompoundExpression, Set, Catch, CompoundExpression, 
  CompoundExpression, Set, Sum`SumConvergenceDump`SumIntegralTest, 
  Block, CompoundExpression, Set, Quiet, Check, CompoundExpression, Set}
*)
```

The `foo = Stack[]` may be omitted.  It was only to prove `SumConvergence` made the journey to the integral test of `term`.

---

*Update: Less hacky -- user-defined test.*

```
myIntegralTest[e_, k_] := (* one could also check the hypotheses *)
 FreeQ[Quiet@Integrate[e, {k, 10^10, Infinity}], Integrate];

SumConvergence[Sin[50/n^2], n, Method -> myIntegralTest]
(*  True  *)

SumConvergence[1/n, n, Method -> myIntegralTest]
(*  False  *)
```

Alternatively (again, inadequate checking of hypotheses):

```
myLCT[e_, k_] := SumConvergence[Normal@Series[e, {k, Infinity, 2}], k];

SumConvergence[Sin[50/n^2], n, Method -> myLCT]
(*  True  *)
```

It's odd that there's a hook for user-defined methods in `Sum` and `SumConvergence`, but they're not documented.

---

Another hack, with `term` as above:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Sum`SumConvergenceDump`SumIntegralTest},
 Sum`SumConvergenceDump`SumIntegralTest[Sin[50/n^2], args___] :=
  Sum`SumConvergenceDump`SumIntegralTest[term[n], args];
 SumConvergence[Sin[50/n^2], n]
 ]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Interesting. How did you notice that hidden syntax of `Method`?

Comment: I think the first method I tried was something like `foo[args___] := (Print[{args}]; True)`.  But I confirmed it with `PrintDefinitions` -- the code is inspectable.