# Convergent infinite sum fails to converge in Sum[...]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, summation

It looks like this.

```
Limit[Sum[1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x), {n, -m, m}], m -> ∞]
= -(1/2) Tanh[x/2]

Sum[1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x), {n, -∞, ∞}]
Sum::div: Sum does not converge.
```

Turning on `Regularization` options does not help to converge. What is the problem here?

Comment: Try: `Sum[Re[1/(I (1 + 2 n) π - x)] // ComplexExpand, {n, -∞, ∞}]`

Comment: Another workaround: `(1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x) /. n -> 0) + 
  Sum[1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x) + (1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x) /. 
      n -> -n), {n, 1, Infinity}] // Simplify`

Comment: I was going to refer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133024, but `SumConvergence` only seems to check convergence for "one-sided" sums, which are divergent in this case. (One can still try. For `Direction->1` and `Direction->-1` the function `SumConvergence` applied to `1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x)` returns unevaluated, except for `Method -> "DivergenceTest"`, where it gives `True`. Also, `SumConvergence` gives the same results for the combination`1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x) + (1/((2 n + 1) Pi I - x) /. n -> -n)` from @BobHanlon's comment, whose infinite sum `Sum` does compute. Strange.)